# Meteor and Modals - clearing form fields and resetting forms

Tags: forms, meteor, modal-dialog, uikit

I'm trying to clear forms after they are submitted (using a modal). I've noticed if I try and have a helper function clear the form or clear the fields the next time someone tried to enter data in the form it somehow is caching or saving previous information.

An example of this is someone creating a list called "my fav bars in new york" and saving it. When a user then wants to create another list called "fav bars in brooklyn", the modal still has the info from the previous - and not only that won't actually save the next list the user creates even if they delete what's there and replace it with a new list name.

I've tried everything, doing form.reset(), clearing the fields using a helper function etc. but nothing seems to work. Has anyone ever run into this?

I've even tried this -

```
Template.listSubmit.created = function() {
        var listField = document.getElementById('list-name').value;
        listField.value = "";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that form is auto-completing. You can disable this with:

```
<form autocomplete='off'>
```

Also note that `created` runs **before** the template is rendered, so that won't work. Try using the `rendered` callback instead.

```
Template.listSubmit.rendered = function() {
  $('#list-name').val('');
};
```

Comment: Seems to do a similar thing to Template create. Basically it gets fired when the main template is loaded (in other words the main view AND the modal that gets displayed when you press "create new list"). So essentially it only fires the rendered function once but not every time the modal is triggered. I would assume that it would only fire once the modal is actually loaded and displayed(?)

Comment: Ah - that's an important point. I assumed that `listSubmit` was the template being rendered in the modal. If it isn't then the rendered callback won't directly help.  If it is, then it all depends on how your modal library works. The one we use at Edthena (which I probably should open source) gives you a callback when the actual modal template is rendered to help in exactly this kind of situation.

Comment: I'm using UI Kit. Essentially listSubmit is called from a main layout.html and gets called up when a "create a list" link is clicked...

      `<addlist id="add-list" class="uk-modal uk-width-large-1-1 uk-width-medium-1-1 uk-width-small-1-1 uk-position-cover">
            <div id="list-dialogue" class="uk-modal-dialog uk-margin-remove uk-cover">
                  <a class="uk-modal-close uk-close uk-margin-remove" style="color:#000;font-size:2.2em;font-family:OpenSansBold;"></a>
                  {{> listSubmit}} 
              </div>
        </addlist>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting the `"my fav bars in new york"`, on a mongo collection like this

```
userFavPlaces = new Mongo.Collection('places')
```

You could so something like this

```
Template.list.event({
  'submit #submit':function(){
     userFavPlaces.insert(values,function(err){
       if(!err){
              $('#list-name').val(''); //Jquery
              var listField = document.getElementById('list-name').value = ''; //pure JS
            }
      }
   }
})
```

If not David answers its enough.

Comment: ok, yeah tried that - it triggers the first time I trigger the modal but then not after that.

Comment: How many fields your from have? Example if you have 7 inputs be sure the users fill the 7 input fields and it should work